# Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Order Form]: [Order Form]

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm creating a page wherein I can create multiple order items `(Order__c)` for every order form `(Order_Form__c)` through "New Order Items" button in the Order__c related list. But every time I save, there's this error: `Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Order Form]: [Order Form]`.

Here's the controller:

```
public class NewOrderController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController orderController;
    public Order__c order {get;set;}
    public Order_Form__c orderform {get;set;}
    public String ordfName {get;set;}
    public List<OrderWrapper> orderlist {get;set;} 
    public Integer rowToRemove {get;set;}
    public String acctname {get; set;} 
    Public Id orderformID {get; set;} 

    public NewOrderController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        orderController = controller;
        this.order = (Order__c)controller.getRecord();
        mobile = FALSE;
        orderlist = new List<OrderWrapper>();
        addNewRowToOrdList();



    }
    public void addNewRowToOrdList() {
        List<OrderWrapper> temp_orderlist = new List<OrderWrapper>();
        OrderWrapper newRecord = new OrderWrapper();
        Order__c newOrderRecord = new Order__c();
        newRecord.ord = newOrderRecord;
        newRecord.index = temp_orderlist.size();
        temp_orderlist.add(newRecord);
        for(OrderWrapper ewloop : temp_orderlist) {
            orderlist.add(ewloop);
        }
    }

    public void removeRowFromOrdList() {
        List<OrderWrapper> rem_orderlist = new List<OrderWrapper>();
        for(OrderWrapper ewloop : orderlist) {
            rem_orderlist.add(ewloop);
        }
        rem_orderlist.remove(rowToRemove);
        orderlist.clear();
        for(OrderWrapper reloop : rem_orderlist) {
            orderlist.add(reloop);
        }
    }

    public void save() {

        List<OrderWrapper> sv_orderlist = new List<OrderWrapper>();
        List<Order__c > newOrderList = new List<Order__c >();
        Order_Form__c orderform = new Order_Form__c();
        Id orderformId;
        Decimal total = 0;
        for(OrderWrapper ewloop : orderlist) {
            sv_orderlist.add(ewloop);
        }

        if(sv_orderlist !=null && !sv_orderlist.isEmpty()) {

            for(OrderWrapper eachRecord : sv_orderlist) {
                Order__c ordTemp = new Order__c ();
                ordTemp.Total_Price__c = eachRecord.ord.Total_Price__c;
                ordTemp.Product__c = eachRecord.ord.Product__c;
                ordTemp.Quantity__c = eachRecord.ord.Quantity__c;
                ordTemp.Order_Form2__c = orderform.id;
                newOrderList.add(ordTemp);

            }
        }

        if(newOrderList.size() > 0) {
            insert newOrderList;
        }

    }

    public class OrderWrapper {

        public Integer index {get;set;}
        public Order__c ord {get;set;}

    }

}
```

And here's vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="NewOrderController">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Order" subtitle="New Order"/>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages /> 
        <apex:pageBlock title="Order" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Order Information">
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Order_Form2__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product Information">
                <apex:outputPanel id="tablepanel">
                <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!orderlist}" var="o">

                        <apex:column headerValue="Action" style="width:80px">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Remove" style="color:red" action="{!removeRowFromOrdList}" rendered="{!rowNum > 0}" rerender="tablepanel" immediate="true" > 
                                <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="rowToRemove" assignTo="{!rowToRemove}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                            <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Product Name" >
                            <apex:inputField value="{!o.ord.Product__c}" required="true"/>
                        </apex:column>  

                        <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" >
                            <apex:inputField value="{!o.ord.Quantity__c}" required="true"/>
                        </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                <apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!addNewRowToOrdList}" rerender="tablepanel"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with line `ordTemp.Order_Form2__c = orderform.id` in your controller's save method. You have to assign correct parent object Id. Currently you are assigning blank Id that's why it is throwing "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING" exception.

Comment: How can I assign the correct parent object Id? I assigned orderform as the parent object, so I thought creating a reference to the master is enough

Comment: I think you should pass parent object Id through `this.order.Order_Form2__c`. So your statement would be `ordTemp.Order_Form2__c = this.Order_Form2__c`. Let me know if you still facing issue.